# Change the focused item background color for all text fields in winforms using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, devexpress

I have full application developed has 500+ controls in 30+ forms and setting each controls background color is not a good idea. Is there any auto way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own text box control (e.g. `TextBoxEx`) and then replace all occurrences of `TextBox` by `TextBoxEx` in your source with the Replace function of the editor. Make sure to set "Match case" and "Match whole word".

Placing this control in the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace will make search replace easier.

```cs
namespace System.Windows.Forms;

public class TextBoxEx : TextBox
{
    private static Color FocusColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 128);
    private static Color DefaultBackColor = Color.White;

    protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        BackColor = FocusColor;
        base.OnEnter(e);
    }

    protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        BackColor = DefaultBackColor;
        base.OnLeave(e);
    }
}
```

The focused textbox will keep its focus color when the form loses its focus. If you prefer to restore the default back color when the form loses its focus, override `OnGotFocus` and `OnLostFocus` instead.

Or you can assign a weaker focus color when the form loses focus like this:

```cs
namespace System.Windows.Forms;

public class TextBoxEx : TextBox
{
    private static Color FocusColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 128);
    private static Color WeakFocusColor = Color.LightYellow;
    private static Color DefaultTextBackColor = Color.White;

    private bool _isFocused;

    protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        _isFocused = true;
        base.OnEnter(e);
    }

    protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        _isFocused = false;
        base.OnLeave(e);
    }

    protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        BackColor = FocusColor;
        base.OnGotFocus(e);
    }

    protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isFocused) {
            BackColor = WeakFocusColor;
        } else {
            BackColor = DefaultTextBackColor;
        }
        base.OnLostFocus(e);
    }
}
```